# Unable to get Sign Ins for Service Principal using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to use [`List SignIns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to get a list of sign-ins for my Service Principal however the API is not returning any results when I try to filter the results by Service Principal id and/or Service Principal Application Id. If I remove the filter, I am able to get the data.

Essentially I am trying to get the data shown in Azure Portal as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have tried both `Graph Explorer` as well as `Microsoft.Graph` SDK (C#) and in both places I am not getting any result back.

Things I tried:

- In Graph Explorer, I tried the following request URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=id eq 'my-service-principal-id'` and that did not give any results back.
- I even tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=appId eq 'my-application-id'` and still no results.
- I tried with both `beta` and `1.0` version numbers and same results.

I checked the Azure Portal network request in browser and noticed that instead of using `graph.microsoft.com`, it is using `graph.windows.net` and is sending the following request:

`https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/activities/getSummarizedServicePrincipalSignIns(aggregationWindow='1d')?$filter=(createdDateTime ge 2021-04-21T13:03:32.608Z and createdDateTime lt 2021-04-28T13:03:32.608Z and (appId eq 'my-application-id' or contains(tolower(appDisplayName), 'my-application-id')))&$top=50&$orderby=createdDateTime desc&source=kds`

I also read the documentation for `List SignIns` API and following caught my eye:

> Retrieve the Azure AD user sign-ins for your tenant. **Sign-ins that are
> interactive in nature (where a username/password is passed as part of
> auth token) and successful federated sign-ins are currently included
> in the sign-in logs**.

I am not sure if what I am trying to accomplish is even possible with Graph API considering I am not getting any results back and Azure Portal is not even using Graph API to get this data.

Any insights into this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using the 'beta' endpoint - but at this point it only seems to include 'interactive' sign-ins by default. If you add a filter on signInEventTypes it can return other types too:

So for 'User sign-ins (non-interactive)':

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'nonInteractiveUser')
```

For 'Service principal sign-ins':

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'servicePrincipal')
```

For 'Managed identity sign-ins':

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'managedIdentity')
```

For all sign ins (let me know if there's a more concise way!

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'interactiveUser' or t eq 'nonInteractiveUser' or t eq 'servicePrincipal' or t eq 'managedIdentity')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-all-sign-ins#return-log-data-with-microsoft-graph

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I posted the question, I did try the beta endpoint though I tried to filter by service principal/application id and not by `signInEventTypes`. Let me try that out as well.

Comment: What are the "t: t" values for please?

Comment: @Russeller The 't: t' values are the property for the 'any' operator - they can be named almost anything e.g. 'x: x' or 'eventtypes: eventtypes' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#any-operator

Answer (score 1):

Beta API has ServicePrincipalId and ServicePrincipalName, you can filter based on these attributes. This link lists the supported Attributes in $filter. This API supports $filter, $skiptoken and $Top.How ever do note Beta API are subjected to change.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#attributes-supported-by-filter-parameter

Here's a blog about graph.windows.net and graph.microsoft.com

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

Comment: Thanks! I believe I tried filtering but it didn't work. Let me try it again. Will revert with my finding.